# post image to facebook wall from as3

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-as3-api

I know how up image to album:

```
public function postImage(img:BitmapData):void
{           
    var params:Object = { photo:new Bitmap(img), 
                          message:'Test Photo', 
                          fileName:'FILE_NAME',                               
                          access_token:Facebook.getAuthResponse().accessToken
                        };
    Facebook.api('me/photos', onSavedPhoto, params, 'POST');
}
```

It work. BUT, how to post uploaded image to wall? Probably need use method 'me/feed', but how to know uploaded image link? Or is there some method to send the image directly on the wall?

Comment: Just curious, which Facebook library are you using?  Do you have a link to it?

Comment: this is "facebook-actionscript-api" library: https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/